# PHP Form index undefined and variable undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html, ebay-api

been doing a simple search, but I have come in to a problem. I get an error of index undefined and variable undefined on my _POST request!
I can't really find the mistake, could anyone help me? The project is done on 3 different files by the way.

HTML:

```
<form action="ajax/queries.php" method="POST" class="searchbox sbx-google">
  <div role="search" class="sbx-google__wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Įveskite paieškos terminus" autocomplete="off" required="required" class="sbx-google__input">
    <button type="submit" title="Submit your search query." class="sbx-google__submit">
      <svg role="img" aria-label="Search">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-search-13"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <button type="reset" title="Clear the search query." class="sbx-google__reset">
      <svg role="img" aria-label="Reset">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-clear-3"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('.searchbox [type="reset"]').addEventListener('click', function() {  this.parentNode.querySelector('input').focus();});
</script>
```

PHP before editing, I get index undefined error, though on queries.php page, I can see the contents of `search`, though it still shows off as an error and doens't supply it to the processing script:

```
global $query;
//
$query = htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);
```

PHP after editing, I get variable undefined error:

```
//Query
if (!isset($_POST)) {
  if (!isset($_POST["search"])){
    $query = htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);
  }
}
```

EDIT:

adding some more code: 
https://pastebin.com/XcKPvWvb  queries.php 
https://pastebin.com/v7cL6Jw5 paieska.php (query doesn't get supplied to it)
`pastebin dot com slash jh5wLPLR` index.php (html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your form, you gave the `name="search"` for the form, input field, and also for the button which made an confusion

**Updated Html**

> I changed method from GET to POST, also changed the name of form,and the search button

```
<form action="ajax/queries.php" method="POST" name="search_form" class="searchbox sbx-google">
  <div role="search" class="sbx-google__wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Įveskite paieškos terminus" autocomplete="off" required="required" class="sbx-google__input">
    <button type="submit" title="Submit your search query." name="search_button"  class="sbx-google__submit">
      <svg role="img" aria-label="Search">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-search-13"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
```

Just a small mistake.. on each `if(isset..` conditions you had used **! (not)** Operator

**Updated PHP code**

```
if (isset($_POST['search_button'])) {
  if (isset($_POST["search"])){
    $query = htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ohoo... on your html `<form action="ajax/queries.php" method="get" name="search" class="searchbox sbx-google">` you are using the method **get** and trying to fetch the data as **post** in your php ......

Comment: either make your form method `<form action="ajax/queries.php" method="post"  `or change your php to $_GET instead of $_POST

Answer (score 0):

PHP: You've been doing your if statement in the wrong order. Please try your if statement like this:

```
// Check if the post variable is set:
if (isset($_POST)) {
// Check if the key search post variable is set:
  if (isset($_POST["search"])){
    // Define the query:
    $query = htmlspecialchars($_POST["search"]);
  }
}
```

HTML: I can't see that have assigned the name of the input, please make sure you do this so the input will be posted with the key as the name of the input.

If I can help you any further, please let me know.

Comment: That is because the HTML part of your code is not done well, it's missing a name on the input.

Comment: Still undefined variable errors in both of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `!` in both `!isset()`s.